# Are defect levels some eigenvalues of a Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

When I read this textbook, [Fundamentals of defect ionization and transport](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781848820586-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-648104-p173847316) on the bottom line of page 9, they say that those ionization levels are not eigenvalues of a SE and they're thermodynamic quantities based on occupation statistics. However, I also learnt that by doing an analogy to the central potential, we can readily calculate those levels with SE. So what is that I misunderstand?

Comment: I'm not sure how 'readily' one may calculate them. Getting good numbers for defect/impurity states in the gap can take quite some doing with DFT, but ultimately it can be done. However, it is substantially more complex than writing down a 'simple' Schrodinger equation and solving it analytically.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks! But however complex the SE, in principle we can still write it down and solve it right? So those levels are still eigenvalues of such monstrous SE. And on the other hand, the K-S equations used in DFT, are still some kind of like  of SE. But in the textbook, they simply say that they're not eigenvalues, and they originate from thermodynamics. I can understand that in order to get the concentration of those defects, we need to use Fermi-Dirac statistics, but still, those levels are calculated in the first place by like you say DFT computation, so what do I miss?

Comment: @JonCuster I'm desperate for an answer, can you point it out why they say that? And I still can't see how the law of mass action can lead to Equ.2.11, I think it is purely derived from the Fermi-Dirac statistics. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can someone just help me...

Comment: First, it should come as no surprise that impurities or defects may have states in the bandgap - it is only the host crystal that has no Bloch states that correspond to that energy. Second is a caveat - isolated impurity or defect states are _not_ Bloch functions - we get sloppy as we change from a full E vs k band structure to a band 'diagram' with impurity/defect states in it. Third, the potential seen by some defect configuration can be very complex, and generally will not yield a 'simple' Schrodinger equation. Fourth, none of this invalidates the law of mass action.

Comment: I can't say how happy I'm to get a reply, thanks! I get the points except the last one. I know that the law of mass action won't be violated but I simply can't see how this law can lead to the expression of the defect concentration which is obviously a result of Fermi-Dirac statistics.

Comment: All the law of mass action implies is that if you have some chemical formula that there is some equilibrium point and an equilibrium constant that depends on the relative energies of the products and reactants. Since the relative energies of reactions between defect states in the gap and charges (electrons or holes) clearly involves the position of the Fermi energy, then it is not surprising that the reaction constant will be expressed with reference to the Fermi energy. And, if you change the Fermi energy, you change the equilibrium point.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks! I totally forgot that the law essentially implies that there's an equilibrium point and just thought of those equations! Now I think I really understand these things, thanks!

Comment: (Hence my original comment about did you really understand the law of mass action...)

Comment: @JonCuster Now I understand that! I really appreciate you help!